# Cant call functions when placing class in seperate file

Tags: c++

So Im new to C++, im trying to create a function to calculate the area of a triangle when the user inputs the base and height, however whenever i try to build and run this program I get an error saying: ISO C++ forbids declaration of "calcArea" with no type [-fpermissive]

Area.h

```
#ifndef AREA_H
#define AREA_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Area
{
    private:
        int base;
        int height;
    public:
        Area();
        int calcArea();


};
#endif // AREA_H
```

Area.cpp

```
#include "Area.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Area::Area()
{
    cin >> base;
    cin >> height;
};

Area::calcArea(){
int answer;
answer = base * height;
return answer;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the return type.

```
  int Area::calcArea(){
//^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current

```
Area::calcArea(){
   int answer;
   ...
```

definition misses to specify a return type matching the declaration `int calcArea();` from your `Area` class declaration.

As T.C. already showed it needs to be

```
  int Area::calcArea(){
//^^^
      int answer;
      ...
```